# Can I use multiple pseudo selectors focus with before/after on the same element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'm trying to combine using pseudo selectors with pseudo elements to create a custom tooltip.

My HTML:

```
<input id='test'/>
```

My CSS:

```css
#test {
    position: relative;
}

#test:focus {
    background-color: #08c;
}

#test:focus:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

A fiddle running the code: http://jsfiddle.net/9ujEH/

Currently the input will change to blue when focused as a result of #test:focus but the black sqaure doesn't show up like I thought it would from #test:focus:before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pseudo elements can only be defined on container elements. Because of the way they are rendered within the container itself as a DOM element. inputs cannot contain other elements hence they're not supported. A button on the other hand, although a form element, supports them because it's a container of other sub elements.

[More from the 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content)

The `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements are now using the double-colon to avoid confusion with pseudo-classes (which obviously use `:`), although older version of IE (7,8) won't recognize the double colons .. keep that in mind if your trying to support them.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work because `input`, like `img`, elements are void/replaced elements, and have no 'content' to speak of, therefore it seems there's no place for the pseudo-elements to be inserted within the elements.

Using a `div`, for example, you *can* use multiple psuedo-selectors, such as:

```
div:hover::before {
    /* CSS */
}
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/9ujEH/1/).

References:

- [Replaced Elements, from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Replaced_element).

Answer (score 4):

**You can achieve what you are trying to do by using the [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) CSS pseudo-class.**

**Just wrap your `input` element in a `<div>` (or any container element) as shown:**

```html
<style>
    #test {
        position: relative;
    }

    #test:focus {
        background-color: #08c;
    }

    #mydiv:focus-within::after {
        content: "Careful! This field is case-sensitive!";
    }
</style>

<div id='mydiv'>
    <input id='test' />
</div>
```

Related:

- [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) CSS pseudo-class
- [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) CSS pseudo-elements

Answer (score 2):

**:after** & **:before** is not working on **replaced** element & `input` is an **replaced** element.

Check this http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a `placeholder`, here's a simple cross-browser option. Works also in IE.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktsx82d3/)

Additionally, you can style as you wish.

```css
i[data-hint]::after      {
  /* position: absolute; */
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(data-hint);
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-style: normal;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.45s ease-out;
}

input:focus + i[data-hint]::after {
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input /><i data-hint="Here my hint for input.."></i>
```